# Tray Icon stopped appearing after invoking Shell_NotifyIcon too frequently

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-10

I am displaying a tray notification popup like this

```
NOTIFYICONDATA ni = { 0 };
ni.cbSize = sizeof(ni);
ni.hWnd = gHwnd;
ni.uID = 1;
ni.hIcon = ghIcon;
ni.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_INFO;
ni.dwInfoFlags = NIIF_INFO;
ni.uTimeout = 2000;
_tcscpy_s(ni.szInfo, _countof(ni.szInfo), _T("Test notification"));
_tcscpy_s(ni.szInfoTitle, _countof(ni.szInfoTitle), _T("myapp"));

Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &ni);
```

It worked fine until recently - the tray icon popped my test notification. Then during testing I called `Shell_NotifyIcon` faster than every 2 seconds, and now absolutely no notifications from my app are displayed. A reboot does not help. The only thing that helps is to give my executable another name or log in as another user.

The question is - how to restore my app to the working order, so that notifications are visible again?

Comment: I probably got moved into the overflow area, click on the < glyph, the one with the "Show hidden icons" tooltip.  Which tray icons are always visible is configurable.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of this limitation before.

I have two suggestions:

- Delete the Icon values in `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify`
- Search the registry for your exe filename and delete the entries you don't recognize (WER, AppCompat etc.).